# Use backend in reactjs, contact form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I am doing my first website using reactjs and I am trying to complete the contact form page and is taking me 2 days so far. I am using nodemailer and as for the configuration part, I'm using Gmail account with OAuth2.

The user will send name, email and message and the form will be sent to my email address. After I press 'send' button url changes to http://localhost:3000/contact (as I have targeted in `package.json` file) but nothing appears in the page and not even in the console.

I don't know how to debug it and an error like this appears

> 'main.1932aa17.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'.

I would be so happy if someone helps.

**index.js** file inside **server** folder

```
 import 'babel-polyfill'
 var express = require("express");
 import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

 import mailer from './mailer'

 const app = express()
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

 app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Server is working.')
 })

 app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
  const { email = '', name = '', message = '' } = req.body

  mailer({ email, name, text: message }).then(() => {
    console.log(`Sent the message "${message}" from <${name}> ${email}.`);
    res.redirect('/#success');
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(`Failed to send this: "${message}" from <${name}> 
 ${email} with this error ${error && error.message}`);
    res.redirect('/#error');
   })
 })

 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

 app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`App is listening on port ${PORT}!`);
 })*
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js doesn't support import statement. You have to use `require`.

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser')`

and

`require("babel-polyfill");`

Comment: still is not working, is giving me the same error :(

Comment: removed `import mailer from './mailer'` also?